# Google analytics ios screen views

Tags: ios, google-analytics-api

I've already integrated google analytics SDK v3 in my iOS application and I need now to track the screen views. Here is what I'm currently seeing on their website:

[image]
Here is the code I'm using(Manual Screen Measurement):

```
+ (void)setupGoogleAnalytics
{
    // User must be able to opt out of tracking
    [GAI sharedInstance].optOut = NO;
    // Initialize Google Analytics with a 120-second dispatch interval. There is a
    // tradeoff between battery usage and timely dispatch.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 120;
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:[infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"] trackingId:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TOKEN];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIAppVersion value:[infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];

}

 + (void)dispatchLogView:(NSString *)viewName Category:(NSString *)category  action:(NSString *)action label:(NSString *)label value:(NSNumber*)value withProperties:(NSDictionary *)dictProp
{
    NSMutableDictionary *event = [[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:category
                                            action:action
                                             label:label
                                             value:value] build];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:event];

    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIScreenName value:viewName];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIDescription value:viewName];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];

    [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
}
```

SetupGoogleAnalytics is called on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. After making these changes, I'm still seeing zero under the "Screen Views"&"Screens/Session" sections. Honestly, I don't know what I'm missing to have it working properly. Here is the link I used to integrate it https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/screens#manual

Does anyone encounter the same problem before? Does anyone have any input on this?

Thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried the following method in order to be able to track the screens on Google Analytics. You may try it out to see if it works for you.

First of all, make sure that the header files and also the project has been configured properly according to the guide provided by Google: [Google Analytics SDK for iOS v3 - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/)

Next, under the **viewDidLoad** for the screen that you want to track:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Home Screen"];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
}
```

Under the **viewDidAppear**:-

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.screenName = @"Home Screen";
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

It is no mistaken. `self.screenName` **must** be placed before `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` in order for the screen to be tracked on Google Analytics. It is weird but it can only work in some special situations on my own project. May be it will work on your project too.

**Note:** The screen name for both the **viewDidload** and **viewDidAppear** should be the same.

Comment: Today, I refreshed Google analytics page and finally, it shows 112 for the iOS screen views but I don't know how they got them (I've tried too many solution, I don't know which one was the correct one). My question is: does Google analytics takes time to refresh/display the updated values since it is not a real time data?

Comment: Yes, it does take some time for it to show, at least 12 hours. But there is a feature "Real-Time", it should display the real time data. I suggest you to put the tracking code on both viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear. It will treat them as one single screen as long as the screen names are the same in the same view controller.

Comment: Thanks for you input, it was the case. I need to wait for at least 12 h to see the updated data on Google analytics page.

Comment: why dont you just use viewWillAppear? then you don't need to bother with setting the variable before calling super on viewDidAppear. You don't even need to override viewDidAppear then.

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this and it works.
 For each of my ViewController's viewDidAppear:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"XXX view"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

And I add this in AppDelegate's didFinishLauching

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXXXXXX-X"];
```

The kGAILogLevelVerbose logs its activity sending to server every 20s, and so that you can see it. This is for debug purpose in your case only, make sure to comment it out before you submit your app.

In addition, you should be able to see your screen on Real-Time screenView that there's 1 user when you're debugging.

Good Luck.

Comment: @Maystro You made sure you setup the GAI in didFinishLauching?

Comment: Honestly, it seems my implementation was correct since the data is being updated now every day. The problem was that I didn't know I need to wait at least 12 hours to get the data updated properly. Thanks for you input but I can't accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**General Setup**

Taken from the Google Analytics iOS documentation.
You might want to add some of them to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

// Initialize tracker. Replace with your tracking ID.
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];
```

Additionally you have two options to track view controller events.

**Option A** - Implementing automatic screen measurement

Let google analytics automatically measure views in your app, have your view controllers extend `GAITrackedViewController`. Set a property called `screenName` with the name of the screen that you want to appear in your reporting.

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : GAITrackedViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.screenName = @"Your screen name that should show up in Google Analytics";
}
```

**Option B** - manually tracking screen events

Manually trigger an event for each of your desired ViewController.
Add the following to your view controller's `viewDidAppear`

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Your screen name that should show up in Google Analytics"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker?.set("Home Screen", value: "Home Screen")
    let screenTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()
    tracker?.send(screenTracker as! [AnyHashable: Any])
```

Answer (score 0):

hello @Maystro you have to set a date at GoogleAnalytics account TODAY,
and then you can see your current events there. if you don't then. 
I read that you said "  Thanks for you input, it was the case. I need to wait for at least 12 h to see the updated data on Google analytics page. –  Maystro Jun 27 at 6:34 "

and please apply

```
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 10;
```

For quick response each 10sec.
and check following block which you applied in your AppDelegate.m 
by calling

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self startGoogleAnalytics];
    ....//your other code
}

- (void)startGoogleAnalytics
{
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{kAllowTracking: @(YES)};
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];

    // User must be able to opt out of tracking

    [GAI sharedInstance].optOut =
    ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"allowTracking"];

   // Initialise Google Analytics with a 120-second dispatch interval. There is a
   // tradeoff between battery usage and timely dispatch.

    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 10;
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"XYZ_Tracker"
                           trackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];
}
```

and then send your screen status using

```
self.screenName = @"Your screen name that should show up in Google Analytics";
```

or

```
[[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Your screenName"]build]];
```

Hope! Your requirement will be solve by above steps